# Как через :nth-child игнорировать каждый третий дочерний елемент?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как через `:nth-child` игнорировать каждый **третий** дочерний элемент?

Answer (score 3):

`:not` + `:nth-child`

```css
p:not(:nth-child(3n)) {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
<p>7</p>
<p>8</p>
<p>9</p>
<p>10</p>
</div>
```

`:nth-child`

```css
p:nth-child(3n+1),
p:nth-child(3n+2) {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
<p>7</p>
<p>8</p>
<p>9</p>
<p>10</p>
</div>
```